# how can search this array

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Given N integers, write an algorithm (in pseudocode form) to count the total pairs of integers that have
a difference of K.
Inputs
Number of integers N, the difference K and the list of elements.
Output
One integer telling the number of pairs that have a difference of K.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the Job:

```
   START
   # Variables Initialization
   init Decision = 'continue';
   init N = 0;
   init integers_array = array();

   # Getting the list of Integers
    Do{
      prompt "Insert an Integer";
      input inserted_int;
      integers_array.push(inserted_int);
      prompt "Choose: Done or continue?!";
      input Decision;
    }while not (Decision == 'continue'); 

   # Getting the Searched Difference
    prompt "Insert the searched difference:";
    input K;

   # Preparing the search phase
    N = count(integers_array);
    init pairs_counter = 0;

    # Make a double loop on the same Integers array, and increment the counter when find          
      pairs, every pair will be counted twice!
    foreach (int i=0; i<N; i++){
       foreach (int j=0; j<N; j++){
           if (absolute(integers_array[i] - integers_array[j]) == K){
              pairs_counter++;
           }
       }
    }

    # Divide by two to get the real number of Pairs
    true_pairs_counter = pairs_counter/2;

    output true_pairs_counter;

   END
```